# hiding the dropdown arrow in choicemenu

Tags: forms

In creating forms is it possible to hide or even remove the dropdown arrow in ChoiceMenu?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}


\ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Bofur,name=whatdwarf,
     ]{Select funniest name, or add one}
     {Bofur,Thorin,Gollum,Smaug,Gandalf}


\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Could you please give a compilable but minimal example of your form? It is a lot of work for possible helpers to type the code for you and btw. we would have to guess around in order to provide a good answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strolling through the [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) source reveals that there are a number of options that control the format of `\ChoiceMenu`. All of these options are are documented in section 6.2 of the manual, but the description is rather terse. This seems to be what is available:

[image]

This said, the output is browser dependent as I get different output with skim (above) and acrobat. Here is the hacked version of the OP's MWE that produced this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\noindent\textbf{combo=true}\newline
\ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Bofur,name=whatdwarf,combo=true
     ]{Select funniest name, or add one}
     {Bofur,Thorin,Gollum,Smaug,Gandalf}


\bigskip\noindent\textbf{combo=false }\newline
\ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Bofur,name=whatdwarf,combo=false
     ]{Select funniest name, or add one}
     {Bofur,Thorin,Gollum,Smaug,Gandalf}

\bigskip\noindent\textbf{radio=true}\newline
\ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Bofur,name=whatdwarf,radio=true
     ]{Select funniest name, or add one}
     {Bofur,Thorin,Gollum,Smaug,Gandalf}

\bigskip\noindent\textbf{hidden=true}\newline
\ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Bofur,name=whatdwarf,hidden=true
     ]{Select funniest name, or add one}
     {Bofur,Thorin,Gollum,Smaug,Gandalf}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```